# Reorder by date with Ajax jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, date

I have a `<li>` with the possibility to drag and drop each item to reorder them and store the new rank to DB

here's the code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#reorder').sortable({
        opacity: 0.6, 
        data:$(this).sortable("serialize"),
        cursor: 'move', 
        tolerance: 'pointer', 
        revert: true, 
        placeholder: 'state', 
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        update: function(e, ui){
            newRank = $(this).sortable("serialize");
                console.log(newRank);
                $.ajax({
                url: base_url + "/admin/rank/",
                type: "POST",
                data: newRank,
                complete: function(success){
                     $("#message").html('<span class="success">file ordered</span>'); 
                },
                error: function(error){
                     $("#message").html('<span class="success">file not ordered</span>');
                }
                });
        }
    });

});
```

Then call the controller :

```
function save_rank()
{
    $items = $this->input->post('item');
    $total_items = count($this->input->post('item'));

    for($item = 0; $item < $total_items; $item++ )
        {

        $data = array(
            'project_id' => $items[$item],
            'rank' => $item
        );

        $this->db->where('project_id', $data['project_id']);
        $this->db->update('ft_projects', $data);
    } 
}
```

This works well and reorder my items by their rank *(in DB I have a column called `RANK` which have the position of each items)*

But now I would like to make a button to REORDER the items by their DATE (stored in DB too) so in fact change the `RANK COLUMN` to have items sorted by `DATE` instead of actual rank (made by user for example)

Comment: If the reordering is on client-side, we'll need to see your markup I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reorder your `li`s you just have to `detach` them and reinsert (`append`) in the parent element again. If the dates are in your DB, you'll have to make an ajax call to retrieve them when the REORDER button is pressed, and in its callback do these operations:

1. detach every `li`;
2. loop through your ajax data, finding which `li` corresponds to the sorted item;
3. append it back.

Although it's better to cache this date information, IMHO, so the delay between "pressing the button" and "the elements reordering" won't be too long. If you want to store additional data to an element, but without displaying it, you can use jQuery's [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function.